# Multiple keys for connect SSH Ubuntu 18.04. How to use?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, system, public-key

Now I already have ssh key authorization.
How can I add another key (my partner's key) so that my friend can ssh to the server using his key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add his public key in authorized_keys folder under ~/.ssh folder

.ssh
it should be under that user who is going to login